# Comparing Height of Web Page against Scroll %

Tags: r, regression

I have a collection of 108 data points in the following format:

```
 page height | % of users who scrolled upto 25% of page | 50% | 75% | 100% (full page)
```

I'm trying to find the influence of page height on the percent viewership of scroll.

I tried to do regression testing with R, but completely got lost when I started implementing it because the numbers didn't make sense.

My basic formula structure with R was:

```
data <- lm(page_height ~ twenty_five, data = pagesize_table)
```

The goal is:

- How can I correlate the relationship between page height and % scroll?
- How can I identify the cost of an additional page height versus % scroll? This is tricky because what I want to say is something along the line of "For every 100 pixels added, you lose Y% of users. I know this is possible if I can generate a regression model formula. But not sure how to do it when there are three levels involved.

Head of data:

```
     V1     V2     V3     V4     V5
1  2318 0.1968 0.3793 0.0519 0.0750
2  3402 0.4859 0.2270 0.0162 0.0619
3  5804 0.0756 0.6321 0.0414 0.0080
4 17431 0.1986 0.2838 0.0039 0.0104
5 11841 0.2969 0.3085 0.0000 0.0012
6 13884 0.3837 0.0384 0.0008 0.0000
```

Comment: What is the nature of the `twenty_five` variable? Is it a column of 1's (person did) & 0's (didn't) scroll 25% of the way down? What does `head(pagesize_table)` look like?

Comment: @gung It's % value and V1 (or page_height) is written in pixel. I added a head output

Comment: So is V1 page_height, & the rest are the"% of users..."? How were those %'s computed? (They don't seem to be cumulative, eg.) What is a row here? Usually, a row is a single observation (eg, a patient).

Comment: @gung Each row is a single observation. You can think of it as a patient of different heights, and the percentage represents how much of a medicine traveled through their body (top to bottom)

Comment: What are the different columns, then? V1, etc, isn't very descriptive.

Comment: @gung I mentioned the breakdown in the start of the question, it's page height | % of users who scrolled upto 25% of page | 50% | 75% | 100% (full page)

Comment: So how is it that 19% of a single user scrolled 25% of the way through a page, but 38% of the same single user scrolled 50% of the way through the same single page (row 1, V2 & V3)? Something doesn't quite make sense here. I don't know how this can be answered without more information about your situation & your data.

Comment: @gung Those are good questions. The data for the scroll depth of a page is collected only after the user goes to the next page. For example, Page A is 10,000 pixels, the user scrolls upto 65% of the page and then clicks on a button that will take the user to Page B. When that occurs, the user will be placed in the 75% bucket (but not in 25% or 50% bucket).

Comment: So why isn't the 1st row `1 0 0 1 0`? I still don't understand your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using the cor function.

Also your regression formula might be off.

Try: 
     data <- lm(V1 ~ V2+V3+V4+V5, data = pagesize_table)
Also, make sure to use variable selection techniques like backwards eliminate
In addition, try glm instead of lm
Furthermore, much like the sight, cross validate your final model using another method like forward selection or BIC.

Comment: We are trying to build a permanent repository of high-quality statistical information in the form of questions & answers. We try to avoid one-liners, which would usually be more of a comment than an answer in its own right. Please expand on your answer (for example, you've only answered the first part of the question). If left as it stands it may be converted to a comment.